# Bitmap::Clone() засоряет память

Tags: c++, winapi, утечка-памяти, gdi+

Здравствуйте! Есть некий `Bitmap *bm`, и задача моей программы заключается в том, чтобы постоянно копировать произвольные(но в пределах битмапа) области этого битмапа, и рисовать их

```
Bitmap *bm=0;
void Create()
{
if(bm)
delete bm;
bm=new Bitmap(...);
//рисуем в битмап, здесь всё нормально
Draw();
}
void Draw(HDC hdc)
{
Graphics g(hdc);

g.DrawImage(bm->Clone(...),...); //клонируем, рисуем
//потом снова вызываем эту функцию, и снова
}
```

Проблема в том, что в ходе вызова этой функции память, используемая моей программой постоянно увеличивается, это же утечка памяти, верно?

На всех форумах, сайтах пишут что объекты GDI+ высвобождаются сами, но что-то не заметно. Может быть ошибка не в этом? Что тут нужно делать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну у Вас ведь настолько очевидная утечка, что её можно не заметить, только если глаза закрыть.

```
auto clone = bm->Clone(...);
g.DrawImage(clone,...); 
delete clone;
```

Смотрите пример на MSDN: [Bitmap.Clone()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms536305.aspx)

Comment: Так `delete` нужно вызывать только если выделял память с помощ. `new`

Comment: @АртурКлочко, очевидно `new` вызывается внутри `Clone()`

Comment: О, сейчас попробую

Comment: Да, проблема в этом